# Project guidance - multiple cvs / modification to data frame

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

Just a quick question on a guidance before having my nerves broken ! :)

I have multiple CSV file that i would like to merge to one BIG new CSV file.

All the files have the same exact structure :

```
Muzicast V2;;;;;;;;
Zoom mÈdia sur Virgin Radio;;;;;;;;;
Sem. 16 : Du 15 avril 2016 au  21 avril 2016;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;
TOP 40;;;;;;;;;
Rg;Evo.;Rg-1;Artiste;Titre;Genre;Label;Audience;Nb.Diffs;Nb.Sem
1;+3;4;Twenty One Pilots;Stressed out;Pop/Rock International;WEA;5 982 000;56;18
2;+1;3;Coldplay;Hymn for the weekend;Pop/Rock International;WEA;5 933 000;55;13
3;-2;1;Imany;Don't be so shy (Filatov & Karas remix);Dance;THINK ZIK;5 354 000;55;7
4;-2;2;Lukas Graham;7 years;Pop/Rock International;POLYDOR;5 927 000;54;16
5; =;5;Justin Bieber;Love yourself;Pop/Rock International;MERCURY GROUP;5 481 000;49;21
```

All the cvs files have the same formatting. 
I would like to :
 - open each file one after the other / ignore the 10 first lines 
 - take all the infos with ";" as a separator 
 - insert variables at the beginning of each lines
 - write on a new file with all the infos from each files.

I managed to open a file and made the changes I needed :

```
handle = open(file_dir+'/'+'virgin092016.csv','r')

results = []

for line in handle :
   line = '12;2016;'+line
   line = line.lower()
   line = line.strip()
   line = line.split(';')
   line = line[0],line[1],line[5]
   results.append(line)

   df = pd.DataFrame(results)

print df
```

I managed to open multiple files and create a DataFrame =

```
file_dir = "VIRGIN"
main_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i, file_name in enumerate(os.listdir(file_dir)):

if i == 0 :
    main_df = pd.read_csv(file_dir + "/" + file_name, sep=";")
    main_df["file_name"] = file_name


else :
    current_df = pd.read_csv(file_dir + "/" + file_name, sep=";")
    current_df["file_name"] = file_name
    current_df = current_df

    main_df = pd.concat([main_df,current_df],ignore_index=True)

print main_df
```

But now I have an issue trying to do both of them at the same time.

I am missing a part and I think it is because I am not sure of the order I have to do my code.

Do i have to open open a file make the changes and then write directly to the MAIN.CSV (which will have the final infos of all files) and then do a DataFrame 
OR should i open a file > do a data frame and after that make the changes I need.

I'm new to python... taking multiple online courses and reading books.... but I feel that I'm still not really "pythonic" in my way of thinking.

Help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming all your csv files are in `"./data/"`, defined in `main_dir`, and that the sum of all your csv does not exceed your RAM memory. The trick is to use a temporary variable `current_df` and then to append it to a final dataframe `final_df` with `pd.concat`.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

main_dir = "./data/"
all_files = os.listdir(main_dir)

for i, file_name in enumerate(all_files):
    current_df = pd.read_csv(main_dir+file_name,
                             sep=";",
                             skiprows=10)

    #add here whatever information you need to your dataframe
    #dump the results into a separate file with current_df.to_csv()

    if i == 0:
        final_df = current_df
    else:
        final_df = pd.concat([final_df, current_df], axis=0)
```